# My code is fetching partial data from JSON while on some data it says undefined

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am using Youtube Data API v3 and only partial data is accessible

I am  attaching a picture , it can access items.snippet.title but says undefined on items.snippet.thumnails.high.url.
But on console.log(item) , it shows all the data is available

https://ibb.co/LvL7Dtg

```
   renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}>


          {/* working */}
          {!!item.snippet && (
            <Text style={styles.item}>{item.snippet.title}</Text>
          )}


          {/* Not Working */}
          {!!item.snippet.thumnails && (
            <Text style={styles.item}>{item.snippet.title}</Text>
          )}
         </TouchableOpacity>
      )
```

i want to get thumbnails of youtube playlist but unable to access the thumbnail part

U P D A T E D   Q U E S T I O N : EDIT

https://ibb.co/ZNqCDvS

In attached picture everthing is working fine , but not as my requirement . In Line no 53 if i change this.state.videos[0].snippet... to item.snippet. It throws and error 'undefined'
Kindlye help

Comment: It's `item.snippet.thumnail>>s<<`

Comment: it was a typo mistake . i changed it later but still getting undefined . p.s edited the question

Comment: You are checking `!!item.snippet.thumnails` but then printing `item.snippet.title`. Is that by design?

Comment: yes it is just a check whether item.snippet.thumnails is accessible or not because this code is working with !!item.snippet check

Comment: Try changing `renderItem={({ item })}` to `renderItem={( item )}`

Answer (score 0):

Change your thumnail to thumbnails.

Comment: it was a typo mistake . i changed it later but still getting undefined